# How can I align my itemized list to the right?

Tags: itemize, two-column, multicol, alignment

I would like my itemized list in the second column to be aligned to the right, as currently, the list is aligned to the left of the column.

How can I do this? See below for an example.

**Before**
[image: before]

**After**
[image]

**Here is what I have done to create the first image:**

```
\section{Modules}

\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]\itemsep-2pt
    \item\small{Item 1}
    \item\small{Item 2}
    \item\small{Item 3}
    \columnbreak
    \item\small{Item 4}
    \item\small{Item 5}
    \item\small{Item 6}
  \end{itemize}
\end{multicols}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome! If you post a minimal working example, i.e. a code that can be compiled and produces the first example, you will get much more feedback and a real answer more quickly.

Comment: Would the items have the same  length or not?

Answer (score 1):

Hope `\columnsep` command will help refer below MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\columnsep225pt
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{itemize}
\item sample
\item sample
\item sample
\item sample
\item sample
\item sample
\item sample
\item sample
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but the problem is that there is a small gap between the bullet points and the margin. If you look at my "after" image, there is no gap. I have tried increasing ``columnsep`` but this results in a line break.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{shortlst}

\newenvironment{tabitemize}[1][3]{%
\settowidth{\labelwidth}{\labelitemi}%
\setlength{\leftmargini}{\dimexpr\parindent+\labelwidth+\labelsep\relax}%
\setlength{\shortitemwidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth/#1}%
\begin{shortitemize}}%
{\end{shortitemize}}%

\usepackage{lipsum,showframe}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabitemize}[2]
    \setlength\itemsep{0em}
    \item Item 1
    \item Item 2
    \item Item 3
    \item Item 4
\end{tabitemize}

\end{document}
```

PS: Unfortunately `shortlst.sty` is not come with none of the LaTeX setup, you have to download it manually.